# Pivoting the table like ssrs reports using sql code

Tags: sql, excel, reporting-services, pivot

```
ROW1 |                   18%
     |===========|==================
Row2 |Metric     | Volume  | VALUE 
     |===========|==========|=======
Row3 |Metric1    | 1000    |  10
Row4 |Metric2    | 2000    |  20
```

Is it possible to get the excel report like how we get it in ssrs . Is the above possible in SQL query ?

Comment: In SSRS you can achieve this using the [Matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/create-a-matrix-report-builder-and-ssrs).

Comment: Can you add sample data, like how it is stored, and the final result you want. You can use the PIVOT command in SQL to pivot.